# Reverse String method

Tags: c#, recursion

I've got a nice riddle in C# (I'm kind of starter).
I need to recursively reserve a string (within a method).
I've tried:

```
 public static void ReverseString(string str)
    {
        if(str.Length > 0)
        {
            char ch = str[str.Length-1];
            ReverseString(str.Substring(0,str.Length-2));
            Console.Write(ch);
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work.
I'm allowed to change **only** the text in the 2 first lines of the `if`.
(the `str[str.Length-1]` and `str.Substring(0,str.Length-2)`)

What's my mistake?
thanks

Comment: Always explain "it doesn't work".  Does it print out the wrong values?  Does it throw an exception?  Does it not compile?  What?

Comment: I think the problem is trying to recursively reverse a string, you don't need recursion at all for this task.

Comment: @Matthew It was already explained that it's an academic exercise.  There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: When trying with a string of 3 ch or less it jumps out of the bound of the array. otherwise, wrong print.

Comment: @matan129 You need to console.writeline before the recursive call.

Comment: @matan129 Then start by debugging the application.  See what the actual values are, when it's trying to access an invalid index look at the string, the index it's trying to access, and backtrack to see how it got to where it is, and what it should have used instead.

Comment: @Asad The constraints of the program prohibit that.

Comment: @Matthew, when doing -1 it prints the original string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static void ReverseString(string str)
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        char ch = str[0];
        ReverseString(str.Substring(1));
        Console.Write(ch);
    }
}
```

To explain what's going on, the inner most call of `Console.Write` gets executed first, which because of recursion ends up being the end of the string.  Then when the stack starts closing in, it prints the earlier characters.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I'll tick this as the ans when the site allows me.

Comment: I didn't see your edit before posting mine, +1. I'll leave my answer up just to keep a different expanation.

Comment: @Cemafor, your answer helped me understanding this one a bit deeper, so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this function is supose to print the string in reverse order to the console.  When working with recursion, you should start by assuming the function does what it is supose to do and code around that. Makeing sure any recursive call is done with a smaller data set. In this case, a shorter string.

```
public static void ReverseString(string str)    // example str="cat"
{
    if(str.Length > 0)
    {
        // grabs the last charactor        "t"
        char ch = str[str.Length-1]; 

        // prints the first n-1 charactors in reverse order   "ac"
        ReverseString(str.Substring(0,str.Length-2));

        // prints that last charactor      "t" leads to "act"... not quite right
        Console.Write(ch);
    }
}
```

If you are not allowed (for the sake of the exersise) to change the last line, you could try this.

```
public static void ReverseString(string str)    // example str="cat"
{
    if(str.Length > 0)
    {
        // grabs the first charactor        "c"
        char ch = str[0]; 

        // prints the last n-1 charactors in reverse order   "ta"
        ReverseString(str.Substring(1));

        // prints that last charactor      "c" leads to "tac"... Yeay!!
        Console.Write(ch);
    }
}
```